# OpenShift - Rollback not pointing to previous image

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rollback, openshift-3

I am trying to do rollback for a deployment config. I am not finding the rollback pointing to older image. It always points to the latest image.

I am trying out the following commands.

```
oc rollout undo dc/<name>
oc rollback dc/<name>
oc rollback dc/<name> --to-version=1
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what about check what revision is referred and what revision is remained on your project ?

1. check how many revision can be saved in your deploymentconfig.
   DeploymentConfig keeps 10 revision history by default, you can verify the current revision limits using following command.

```
$ oc get dc/<your dc name> -o yaml  | grep revisionHistoryLimit
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

2. check your deploymentconfig deployment history for checking what revision can be referred
   An you can also list what revision is remained, the "REVISION" number is used for "--to-version"

```
$ oc rollout history dc/<your dc name>
deploymentconfigs "<your dc name>"
REVISION    STATUS      CAUSE
1       Failed      newer deployment was found running
2       Complete    config change
3       Complete    config change
4       Complete    config change
```

3. check current referred revision of your deploymentconfig which shows as "(latest)".

```
$ oc describe dc/<your dc name>
Deployment #4 (latest):
:
Deployment #3:
:
```

I think you can find some message why you can not rollback to old revision through above checking, such as some failed deployment messages or information about that.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried the commands you have provided. When I do a rollback, I find the revision number correctly changing. Lets say we have revisions 1 and 2 with 2 being latest. When I do rollback, i am seeing the revision changed to 1. But the image is still pointed to latest. I am able to make rollback working by using patch command along with the tagging. If there is anything I am missing for the rollback command, please let me know.

Comment: What cause does it be recorded between 1 and 2 revision of the your deployment in your "oc rollout history" output ? Is it "Image change" ? If not, it's used same image between 1 and 2 revision.